# Mocha. Test several test.js

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, mocha.js

I have some architecture:

`NameOfModule
|- module1
|  |- file1.js
|  |- file2.js
|  |- test.js
|
|- module2
   |- file1.js
   |- file2.js
   |- test.js`

etc.

I know how I can run the one test.js. I'm simple run in terminal:

`:~$ mocha`

But I want to run all test.js files from root directory `NameOfModule`. How can I do it from terminal? What is it command?

I have Lubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `mocha` the list of files you want it to load so, with `sh` or `bash` as your shell:

```
$ mocha `find . -name test.js`
```

The `find` command finds all files named `test.js`. The backticks make it so that the output of `find` is passed as arguments to `mocha`.